# Debugging (Old) Ruby Rack via VsCode

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rack, vscode-debugger

I been task to update an old ruby (2.4.10) project.
The project is a simple API server written using [`Cuba`](https://github.com/soveran/cuba/tree/3.8.1) and [`Rack`](https://github.com/rack/rack/tree/2.0.8).
(Note that the project uses [dep](https://rubygems.org/gems/dep/versions/1.1.0)).

I'm trying to setup a working environment on my mac (using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)) and would like to **debug** the API server via VsCode. After hours of searching and testing all sort of `launch.json` configuration I came up empty.

I have created the most minimal representation of the project in at the following repo https://github.com/dannyhuly/ruby-rack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI
I'm a ruby newbie and would like to learn as mach as I can. So any additional information and suggestions would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Could you add information on what you tried and what errors you got during your attempts, if any?

Comment: I tried using `Ruby` and `ruby-debug` VsCode extensions. Both don't work (not even logs) when bundler isn't set. Other then that I wasn't able to advance.

Comment: Can you post steps to reproduce? For example, what launch.json have you tried? And when you say it doesn't work, does it mean you start the debug session and nothing happens, or it doesn't stop at a breaking point? I tried locally and it worked for me, after seeing in the debug console some issues related to dependencies I didn't have installed (mode details in https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/blob/main/docs/debugger.md) and fixing them.

Comment: See this extension description https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.ruby-debug and the default extension just didn't work (no error no info). Please see the provided github repo in the question if you are able to debug it by any means please add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a debug session with your project using the [Ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) extension.

As explained in the [vscode-ruby debugger docs](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/blob/main/docs/debugger.md), first I had to install the `ruby-debug-ide` and the `debase` gems.

Then I used the following *launch.json*:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Rack",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "~/.rbenv/versions/2.4.10/bin/rackup",
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

If there's any issue starting the session, you should be able to see error logs in the *debug console* panel in VSCode.